# access on-prem services from default VPC using lambda hosted in tunneled private VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, dns, amazon-vpc

I am trying to connect one of the on-prem hosted service from my Tunnled VPC. When I access this service from EC2 hosted in tunneled VPC I am able to access it without any problem.

Now I have below situation

I have my app hosted in VPC with internet gateway.
This app needs to connect the On Prem Service mentioned above.

So I am deploying Lambda function in the first Tunneled VPC but when I run query from my Internet gateway VPC I am getting error that its not able to reach to my On-prem service.

for Internal VPC connections I have enabled VPC peering and I can access Ec2 and other services hosted inside both VPC's without any problem vice-versa from both of the VPC's.

please suggest what could I do.

Answer (score 0):

What you described sounds like an edge to edge routing pattern that is unsupported with VPC peering (I'm not sure what the Lambda's role is in the scenario, though). VPC peering only lets the peered VPCs talk to each other, not enable one VPC to use the other's VPN connection or internet gateway.
(https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/peering/invalid-peering-configurations.html#edge-to-edge-vgw)

On the other hand, a Transit Gateway can be a hub and connects multiple VPCs as well as VPN connections.
(https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/scaling-vpn-throughput-using-aws-transit-gateway/)